# How can I update if value is different or empty

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to update my column if the vlaue is different from last value or its empty. I came up with this sql but it gives this error:

> missing FROM-clause entry for table "box_per_pallet"

SQL:

```
UPDATE products AS p
            SET box_per_pallet[0] = (CASE WHEN p.box_per_pallet.length = 0 THEN 0 ELSE p.box_per_pallet[0] END)
            WHERE sku = 'A' AND store_id = 1
```

Comment: You can't replace a single item from an array, you have to replace the entire array.

Comment: What is the datatype of `box_per_pallet`? `ARRAY`? Where is the input for the new value? This is the modifying arrays documentation for postgres: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/arrays.html#ARRAYS-MODIFYING

Comment: @FrankHeikens in postgresql you can

Comment: @JSpratt its array. 0 is the new value , i will replace it with correct value its an example

Comment: What you have there says, "If my existing array isn't empty, then assign the preexisting value to index 0. Otherwise, assign 0 to index 0." I don't see where you're determining its difference from the last value. This may be better handled with an `INSERT` with `ON CONFLICT`

Comment: @JSpratt sorry my bad edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with based on your input. `ARRAY_LENGTH` takes the array and the dimension you want to check the length of as parameters. This `missing from clause` is because Postgres thinks that `p.box_per_pallet` is something other than an array and it can't find that anywhere in the query. You can't use the dot operator on arrays like `p.box_per_pallet.length`. It's like saying, "find the `length` field on table `box_per_pallet` in schema `p`".

```
UPDATE products
   SET box_per_pallet[0] = CASE WHEN ARRAY_LENGTH(box_per_pallet, 1) = 0
                                  OR box_per_pallet IS NULL
                                  OR box_per_pallet[0] <> 0 -- your new value?
                                THEN 0
                                ELSE box_per_pallet[0]
                                END
 WHERE sku = 'A'
   AND store_id = 1
;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5d2e944b7f7fb39e96312018f63effd6) is a link to a dbfiddle showing the idea.